# graphviz - SEM residual covariance

Tags: graph, graphviz

I can't find out how to draw a curved line between two rectangle using `graphviz` such as

[image]

```
digraph G {

SatisfactionF [style=filled, shape = rectangle] 
SatisfactionM [style=filled, shape = rectangle]  
Marital[shape = circle] 

       SatisfactionF -> Marital
       SatisfactionM -> Marital
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
digraph G {

{
rank = same;
SatisfactionF [style=filled, shape = rectangle] 
SatisfactionM [style=filled, shape = rectangle]  
}
Marital[shape = circle] 

       SatisfactionF -> Marital
       SatisfactionM -> Marital


SatisfactionF -> SatisfactionM [label = "0.4" tailport=n headport=n dir=both arrowhead=none]

}
```

[image]

It gives a warning but it works.

Comment: @giacomoV  If this helped you, please "Accept" the answer so it'll show up for others looking for a similar solution, thanks.

Comment: there is an issue when I run it. The line is not curved enough. Do you know how I can force the line to be more curved? thanks

Comment: @giacomoV  Does yours look like the one I posted?  Do you mean arched higher?  I'm looking at the documentation now and see nothing other than splines=curved, which will mess up the rest of your graph.

Comment: I am trying to run it in `R`, it might be why it is not working properly. But thanks